# How to Android Studio LockScreen Wallpaper

Tags: android, lockscreen, wallpapermanager

```
 private void UpdateMyWallpaper()
{
    myWallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    myDrawable = myWallManager.getDrawable();
    myCurrentWallpaper.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
}
```

This work walpaper but i how to lockscreen walpaper set

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void UpdateMyLockWallpaper(){

    myWallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setStream(inputStream, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
    myDrawable = myWallManager.getDrawable();
    myCurrentWallpaper.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i have a problem inputstream cannot resolve symbol 'inputstream'